# Iterate over unique values in dataframe, skip some in R

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration

I want to iterate over unique values in a dataframe in R, that's an extract:

```
for(id in unique(df$event_id)) {
    df_id = df %>% filter(event_id == id)
    
    if(!any(df_id$value == "test")) {
      next
    }

    # function and bind_rows based on current id
    segments = get_segments(df_id) 

    all_segments <- bind_rows(all_segments, segments)
}
```

I get the following error for one unique ID:

> Error in if (!any(df_id$value == "test")) { :    Missing value
> where TRUE/FALSE is needed

The relevant row for this Error has a "NA" in the df_id$value-column. How can I skip this without an error message? I have to change the if condition somehow.

Comment: Try `%in%` instead? Check to make sure it handles `NA`s the way you intend.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the if statement like this to account for NA values:

```
if(!any(df_id$value == "test") | is.na(df_id$value)) {
  next
}
```